# PyQT4 заполнить таблицу

Tags: python, python-3.x, база-данных, pyqt4

В дизайнере добавил на форму TableWidget. Через pyuic4 конвертировал в .py, подключил к проекту.
Вижу, что там создались объекты self.ui.tabWidget, self.ui.tabView.
Объясните пожалуйста как их заполнить данными? Я выполняю селект из базы, получаю набор данных. Как их передать в таблицу?

Comment: А зачем `QTableWidget` и `QTableView`? QTableWidget -- имеет встроенную модель, а QTableView нужно указать модель, например QStandardItemModel. Если QTableView, тогда нужно заполнять ее модель, а модель уже сообщит *View о новых данных и та их отобразит. В случаи с базами данных есть готовые модели: QSqlQueryModel, QSqlTableModel, QSqlRelationalTableModel. Так что какие виджеты вы используете, теми и заполняйте. В общем, документация в помощь: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlquerymodel.html

Comment: Спасибо, все равно не понял( отдельно у меня получилось создать таблицу, как самостоятельное приложение. После конвертации файлв из дизайнера появился объект tableView, как с ним работать? Так же через модель?

Comment: Если tableView это QTableView, то ему потребуется модель. Если у вас данные в базе из одной таблиц, то попробуйте через QTableWidget -- проще будет

Answer (score 3):

Прикладываю пример заполнения таблицы (`QTableWidget`) из таблицы базы данных:

```
try:
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
    from PyQt5.QtGui import *
    from PyQt5.QtCore import *

except:
    from PyQt4.QtGui import *
    from PyQt4.QtCore import *


import sqlite3


class Widget(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle('Table')

        self.table_widget = QTableWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.table_widget)

    def fill(self):
        self.table_widget.clear()

        labels = ['ID', 'NAME', 'PRICE']

        self.table_widget.setColumnCount(len(labels))
        self.table_widget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(labels)

        with sqlite3.connect('games.sqlite') as connect:
            for id_, name, price in connect.execute("SELECT id, name, price FROM Game WHERE kind = 'Finished'"):
                row = self.table_widget.rowCount()
                self.table_widget.setRowCount(row + 1)

                self.table_widget.setItem(row, 0, QTableWidgetItem(str(id_)))
                self.table_widget.setItem(row, 1, QTableWidgetItem(name))
                self.table_widget.setItem(row, 2, QTableWidgetItem(price))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])

    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    w.fill()

    app.exec()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]